# Struts2 Unit test gives the error: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, struts2, junit

I'm trying to run a simple test on my Struts2 action using the method described in the documentation. However, the test class is not instantiated, instead it gives me the following exception:

```
Results :

Tests in error: 
  initializationError(net.myorg.myProj.actions.HomeTest): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

Here is the code of my test class:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class HomeTest extends StrutsTestCase
{    
    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("getting proxy");
        ActionProxy proxy = getProxy();

        System.out.println("got proxy");
        String result = proxy.execute();        

        System.out.println("got result: " + result);

        assertEquals("Landing", result, "landing");
    }  

    private ActionProxy getProxy()
    {
        return getActionProxy("/");
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: In my pom.xml, I've got the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm guessing that this is causing this problem, i.e the jar is not being properly downloaded or included when I just run the unit test from within the IDE rather than via the web browser? How can I include this jar myself so the unit tests will run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to my pom.xml fixed this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In addition, for JUnit4, I had to rewrite my test as the following:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import org.apache.struts2.StrutsJUnit4TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class HomeTest extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase<Home>
{    
    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception
    {
        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/home");
        String result = proxy.execute();
        assertEquals("Landing", "landing", result);
    }
}
```